# ldap_start_tls returns 0x35 for multi threaded applications using winldap

Tags: winapi, openssl, ldap, openldap, starttls

Here is my code to connect to an ldap server using tls using winldap which works fine for a single threaded application , When I integrate the same with a huge application which is multi threaded the same code doesn't work ,
the application failes in ldap_start_tls function , I have verified the possibilities of error , but no clue ,

The error code is 0x35 (LDAP_UNWILLING_TO_PERFORM)

but SSL works fine for my application.

I'm able to authenticate to the ldapserver ,using SSL .

I'm using opends with SSL/TLS enabled

and I tried to set LDAP_OPT_SERVER_CERTIFICATE option and a callback funtion which returns  true to solve certificate related issues.

/*function which works fine for both ssl and TLS if it is single threaded application*/

```
int authCheck( char *host, char *port, char *bind_dn, char *bind_pw, bool TLS)
{
    LDAP *ld;
    int rc;
    int portnumber = atoi( port );

    /* Get a handle to an LDAP connection. */
    if( ( ld = ldap_init(host, portnumber ) ) == NULL ) 
    {
        printf( "Can't initialize %s : %d\n" , host, portnumber );
        return( -1 );
    }

    ldap_set_option( ld, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, &requested_version );
    ldap_set_option(ld, LDAP_OPT_SERVER_CERTIFICATE, &VerifyCert);

    /* If appropriate, switch to a secure connection */

    if (TLS == true)
    {

        rc = ldap_start_tls_s( ld, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);


       if ( rc != LDAP_SUCCESS ) 
       {
            printf( "Can't initialize tls\n" );
            return( -1 );
        }
}
```

Please some one help me to solve the problem ,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any reason you're not calling [ldap_sslinit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367031.aspx)? For working sample code see [Example Code for Establishing a Session over SSL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366105.aspx).

Comment: I have not copied the code for SSL here, as SSL connection works fine  for me , If I integrate the same to my application ,TLS function works fine if it is tested as a simple single threaded application but not for a huge multi threaded application.

Comment: Are you sure, you know what you're doing? This **is** the code to establish an SSL-secured connection. You may want to consider reading the documentation as well. [ldap_start_tls_s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa366997.aspx): *"LDAP_UNWILLING_TO_PERFORM is returned if a TLD/SSL session is already in progress, or if a bind is currently in progress, or if there is an outstanding LDAP request on the connection."*